# Windows API StartService ... localized service name

Tags: c++, localization, windows-services

I want to start the Volume Shadow Copy service with a C++ program. This involves getting a handle to the service control manager ([OpenSCManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684323%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), using this to obtain a service handle ([OpenService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684330%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and then starting the service ([StartService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686321%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

However, I have to pass the service name as a string to the OpenService function. The VSS service is called *Volumeschattenkopie* on my German Windows Vista. Is there a way to start the correct service in any language? I haven't used resource strings before but are service names obtainable with `FindStringResourceEx` or something like that?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that Volumeschattenkopie is the *service name* on German Vista? It is definitely the *service display name*, but OpenService is looking for the name that was used during CreateService, which may not be localized.

Comment: @Jon: Thanks! I see. How do I find out the original name of a service?

Comment: @Felix Go into the services control panel, bring up the properties for the service you are interested in. It says the name right at the top. On my english win7 box, Volume Shadow Copy's service name is VSS

Comment: @Felix: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services`, likely VSS or so ...

Comment: @Jon: indeed you're right. How about an answer I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you absolutely sure that Volumeschattenkopie is the service name on German Vista? It is definitely the service display name, but OpenService is looking for the name that was used during CreateService, which may not be localized. To locate the original service name, go into the services control panel, bring up the properties for the service you are interested in. It says the name right at the top. On my english win7 box, Volume Shadow Copy's service name is VSS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with getting localized names for built-in Windows accounts like 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' or 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.
Only difference is that I use C# in this case. However I think this should not be a problem to transfer to C++ (using unmanaged or managed C++?)

Here is how I get localized 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' on local computer:

```
SecurityIdentifier userIdentifer = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.NetworkServiceSid, null);
string accountName = userIdentifer.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).Value;
```

And if I need 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' then I just use different Sid:

```
SecurityIdentifier userIdentifer = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.LocalSystemSid, null);
```